# Unable to get User Profile Picture With Facebook graph api

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

my angular 2 app uses facebook login to get username, email and profile picture. I am able to get  username and email  But url for profile picture provided by facebook api does not work.

Here is the flow of the app

1. user logs in to facebook from my app with permission to name,email and profile picture
2. After login the app requests for name,email and profile picture using Facebook api
3. app gets response from facebook api containing all the requested data example below

`response : {
      email:"user@mail.com"
      id:"992219737612453"
      name:"user name"
      picture: {
          data:height:50
          is_silhouette:false
          url:"https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/? 
              asid=992219737612453&height=50&width=50&ext=1527274398
              &hash=AeQwwpehQqNhgVxr"
          width:50
      }
}`

But the problem is that url given in the above response for picture does not work and gives error 429. But the same url starts working when it is accessed using vpn. Anyone please figure out what  the problem is and how to solve it.
Note: 429 error stands for too many requests but at facebook developer dashboard page for this app it says your app has not reached level for rate limiting.

**UPDATE: URL is being blocked when it is accessed using specific ISP that belongs to CHINA. But the problem is my most users use that Internet service provider.**

Comment: Are you getting the same result, when you just use `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture`? Do things change, if you append the current app user’s access token to that?

Comment: Yes dear I have tried it but the same response https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture?access_token={user_acces_token}. And when i try it over vpn it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in question its a problem of Internet service provider which works/origin is from CHINA. So, you will need neutral ISP from any region or the of the region on which url works.

The only solution to this problem is that you should setup a server (express best option for angular 2/4 ) hosted on different ISP. And the server gets image from that url and returns it back to the client.

Wrong Architecture:

Client ==================================================> Server containing Image

Client <===============429Error(Due to Different ISP)<=========== Server containing Image

Right Architecture:

Angular  **===================>** Express  **==========>** Server Containing Image

Angular  **<===================** Express  **<==========** Server Containing Image

Answer (score 0):

If this is working over a VPN, it sounds like a permissions issue. What permissions could the VPN allow that the local machine or server you are running from does not have?

Comment: name,email and picture are part of public profile and these are accessible just by having userID even if we do not ask for permission. But still I am requesting/getting permission for name,email and picture.

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim you can not access anyone’s e-mail, unless they explicitly give your app permission.

Comment: dear @CBroe I can access email. The issue is of user profile picture. I also get link for it but the link does not work. But this works over a vpn

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim that may be, if you have asked for the necessary permission. But what you said, _“name,email and picture are part of public profile and these are accessible just by having userID even if we do not ask for permission”_, is definitively wrong - you won’t get anyone’s email without permission.

Comment: Dear @CBroe you are right. my excuse !. But What my problem is I have permission for name,email and profile picture and in response (mentioned above) url given for profile picture does not work over specific ISP. But it works over VPN . So what could be solution ?