# Sammyk/LaravelFacebookSdk - Never returns user profile picture. always return this url: "https://lookaside.facebook.com/etc"

Tags: facebook

I know this type of question has been asked many times. but honestly, NOT A SINGLE one solved my problem.

here is what im coding:

```
                $resPicture =   $FB->get('/me?fields=picture', $token);
                $resBody    =   $resPicture->getGraphUser();
                $resBody    =   $resBody["picture"];
                echo '<img src="'.$resBody["url"].'">';
                dd();
```

and the `img` `src` is: `https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=114975966053890&height=50&width=50&ext=1527323170&hash=AeR3847SlhI8RuNC`

Tried every possible thing but nothing useful.
tell me where im making mistake, any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook graph user picture won't show on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513735/facebook-graph-user-picture-wont-show-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the given URL?

Comment: @NicoHaase the URL does not return any picture

Comment: Have you tried the redirect version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475104/unable-to-get-user-profile-picture-with-facebook-graph-api#comment87975924_50475104

Comment: @CBroe yes I have